# Why does UndistortPoints() fail for these input points?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, distortion

I want to undistort some points in EmguCV, but I get a `CVException` during execution, because the following assertion fails:

```
OpenCV: src.isContinuous() && (src.depth() == CV_32F || src.depth() == CV_64F) && ((src.rows == 1 && src.channels() == 2) || src.cols*src.channels() == 2)
```

Here's how I call the function:

```
                                                      //fx fy,  cx,  cy, k1, k2, p1, p2
IntrinsicParameters intrinsic = new IntrinsicParameters( 1, 1, 100, 100,  0,  0,  0,  0);

VectorOfPoint points = new VectorOfPoint(new Point[] { new Point(0, 0), new Point(255, 255) });
VectorOfPoint pointsUndistorted = new VectorOfPoint(points.Size);

CvInvoke.UndistortPoints(points, pointsUndistorted, intrinsic.CameraMatrix, intrinsic.DistorionCoefficients);
```

explanation:

1. `IntrinsicParameters` is a custom class that wraps all intrinsic parameters, which I used default values for). I added a comment above to denote what parameter is which
2. I create a `VectorOfPoint` called `points` that I want to distort.
3. I create another `VectorOfPoint` to hold the result
4. **The program hangs on the last line** in the snippet provided. When I click pause in VisualStudio the debugger says the mentioned assertion failed.

I tried to find some explanation of what this all means but [there's no comment whatsoever in the openCV source code](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/undistort.cpp#L422).

What am I doing wrong here? Am I not supposed to use `undistortPoints()` with this type of points? But then why can I pass them to the function?

### Update using `Mat`

I tried to use `Mat` instead, which is a bit of a pain to use. [I found this question explaining how to set the elements of a `Mat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255440/how-can-i-get-and-set-pixel-values-of-an-emgucv-mat-image) and came up with this code:

```
int n = 2;
Mat mat = new Mat(new Size(1, n), Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv32F, 2);
Mat matDistorted = new Mat(new Size(1, n), Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv32F, 2);

Matrix<float> yetAnotherMatrixOr_YAM_forShort = new Matrix<float>(new float[,]{{0, 0}, {255, 255}});

mat.SetTo(yetAnotherMatrixOr_YAM_forShort);

CvInvoke.UndistortPoints(mat, matDistorted, intrinsic.CameraMatrix, intrinsic.DistorionCoefficients);
```

The exception I get now comes from a different assertion (hurray?):

```
OpenCV: checkScalar(value, type(), _value.kind(), _InputArray::MAT )
```

It looks like this happens when calling `mat.SetTo()`. I'm not sure why this is so complicated.

Comment: can you try `Point2f` instead of `Point`?

Comment: @Micka how would I do that? EmguCV has `MCvPoint2D64f`, which I can create an array of: `MCvPoint2D64f[]`, but I can neither wrap that into a `VectorOfPoints` nor can I pass it to `CvInvoke.UndistortPoints()`. There's no `VectorOfPoints2f` either. How would I pass many `Point2f ` objects to `CvInvoke.UndistortPoints()`? Whatever it is, I think it has to implement `InputArray`, but am not sure. The type system of this library still confuses me.

Comment: sorry, don't know enough about emguCV... is it possible to create Mat objects with CV_32FC2 equivalent? Like new Mat(size, Cv32F, 2)? Feed your point positions (n points) to it and choose size to be 1 column and n rows.

Comment: @Micka I think I tried something like that, please take a look at my edit. Did I mess up the `Mat`?

Comment: no idea, sorry... .setTo typically means to set each pixel (or matrix element) to a fixed value. Can you try to modify the data of `mat` directly (I don't know how to access matrix elements in emguCV, sorry)?

Comment: @Micka you got me on the right track, while there's no `Point2f` in EmguCV, I managed to solve the problem by using `PointF` instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem was indeed the `Point` class.

Changing the code to use `PointF` and `VectorOfPointF` instead respectively solved the problem:

```
VectorOfPointF points = new VectorOfPointF(new PointF[] { new PointF(0, 0), new PointF(255, 255) });

VectorOfPointF pointsUndistorted = new VectorOfPointF(points.Size);
```