# Converting from EmguCV 3.1 to 3.3 causes code to hang

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

In EmguCV 3.1.X (installed from Nuget) with the non-commercial license I had this code, which I got from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255440/how-can-i-get-and-set-pixel-values-of-an-emgucv-mat-image) and which worked fine:

```
    public static dynamic GetValue(this UMat mat, int row, int col)
    {
        var value = CreateElement(mat.Depth);
        Marshal.Copy(mat.ToMat(AccessType.Read).DataPointer + (row * mat.Cols + col) * mat.ElementSize, value, 0, 1);
        return value[0];
    }
```

I now want to switch to the commercial version of EmguCV 3.3.X (installed from Nuget) and therefore had to change this code into:

```
    public static dynamic GetValue(this UMat mat, int row, int col)
    {
        var value = CreateElement(mat.Depth);
        Marshal.Copy(mat.GetMat(AccessType.Read).DataPointer + (row * mat.Cols + col) * mat.ElementSize, value, 0, 1);
        return value[0];
    }
```

For no apparent reason, this code hangs without exception or anything on the line:
`Marshal.Copy(mat.GetMat(AccessType.Read).DataPointer + (row * mat.Cols + col) * mat.ElementSize, value, 0, 1);`

Am I doing something wrong or could this be bug in EmguCV?

Comment: The library changed so you must rebuild you c# project to use the new dll.  Usually I just delete the bin folder of the c# project to force all code to build.  Make sure you save any files that you manually placed in the bin folder.  when you change a dll the compiler dependencies somethimes do not recognize dll changes

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the "CreateElement" function available, so I used the following code to test. It should be similar.

```
        UMat u = new UMat(new Size(480, 320), DepthType.Cv8U, 1);
        u.SetTo(new MCvScalar(100));

        byte[] value = new byte[1];
        int row = 100;
        int col = 200;

        using (Mat m = u.GetMat(AccessType.Read))
        {
            IntPtr ptr = m.DataPointer + row * m.Step + col * m.ElementSize;
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, value, 0, 1);
        }
```

Tested with the v3.3.0.2824 release from Emgu CV commercial release nuget repository and works without hanging. If you still have the same issue, please upload the complete code and I will take a look.

Thanks.